# Change font size of the values on a scatterplot in python

Tags: python, scatter-plot

How to change the font size of the values on a scatterplot in python next to the axis

I looked at many tutorials and all i go were the ones related to x label and y label instead of the values size as shown on the graph [In this image I have circled in red the part whose size I want to increase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L91Dc.jpg)

Here is the code for reference:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(170,50))  
sns.scatterplot(x= job_size_M.employee_residence, y= job_size_M.salary, hue= job_size_M.employee_residence, s=2000);
plt.xlabel('Countries', size = 100);
plt.ylabel('Salary', size = 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add backticks around the code when you upload it like so.

````
```python
<code go here>
```
````

second you need to add the link like so if you want to get your question answered when sharing a photo. Just for future reference.

```
![In this image I have circled in red the part whose size I want to increase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L91Dc.jpg)
```

[image: In this image I have circled in red the part whose size I want to increase]

And to fix the error you mentioned

Here's how it might look based off of how you have it setup in your code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(170, 50))
sns.scatterplot(
    x=job_size_M.employee_residence,
    y=job_size_M.salary,
    hue=job_size_M.employee_residence,
    s=2000
)
plt.xlabel('Countries', size=100)
plt.ylabel('Salary', size=100)

# Increase the font size of the tick labels
plt.xticks(fontsize=50)
plt.yticks(fontsize=50)

plt.show()
```

Here's another way to write it:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = sns.scatterplot(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[3, 1, 2])
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Here's a useful [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-visualization-with-matplotlib-seaborn-and-pandas-288f63b99751) for further examples of how to modify charts

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font size of the values next to the axis by adding this piece of code:

```
# Adjust the values of 'fontsize' accordingly
plt.xticks(fontsize=100)
plt.yticks(fontsize=100)
```

your final code should look something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(170,50))
sns.scatterplot(
    x= job_size_M.employee_residence, 
    y= job_size_M.salary, 
    hue= job_size_M.employee_residence, 
    s=2000)
plt.xlabel('Countries', size=100)
plt.ylabel('Salary', size=100)

# Adjust the values of 'fontsize' accordingly
plt.xticks(fontsize=100)
plt.yticks(fontsize=100)

plt.show()
```